# Branch office Connectivity issues

Tags: networking, vpn, azure

We have two offices. One in The Netherlands and one in India. In each office we have pretty good internet connection (~20Mbps). The major problem we face is cross office connectivity.

Skype calls are really poor and so are Hangouts. File download speeds are also really poor.

Is there a way to solve this situation?

I am not sure if this is possible at all, but I am thinking of a solution where

1. I create a server with location in Amsterdam on Windows Azure
2. Create another server with Location Singapore on Windows Azure
3. Create a private network to connect these two servers.
4. Define a channel so that my data is through these servers using some kind of proxy setup?

Is this kind of a solution possible at all? What are my options?

Comment: Find the source of your problems before selecting solutions. E.G. Your problems may be more related to latency than lack of bandwidth, although the quality of your local uplinks may not be reflected in the international bandwidth the ISP's provide.. What you get for ping response times? What does a traceroute between the offices show?  (For instance: traffic may be routed via the pacific and US rather than following a path closer to the great circle between India and .NL).

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! There appears to be little to no research done on this issue up front and/or there's very little for someone here to go on to assist you.  It is recommended that you post things you've already tried, options you are considering, or errors that you are experiencing.  The more details you provide (logs, screenshots, etc.), the better the experts here can assist you.

Comment: you need to think more about how you can benefit from what you already have; so you need to think more about something like QoS, optimizing your BGP setup (if any) and using decent network equipment, OSes and solutions like that. you should think less about moving some Windows Azure installations between datacenters. you should describe more your current VPN and network setup.

Answer (score 3):

There is a few obvious possibilities for what you should check next:

- Maybe the 20Mbps capacity specified by the ISP is only for incoming traffic. If the outgoing capacity in each location is smaller, then communication between the two sites will never be able to use the full incoming capacity in either location.
- If either link is saturated in one direction, you may experience increased roundtrip latency and packet drops. With mild cases of buffer bloat, this may increase roundtrip latency by tens of milliseconds, in one extreme case I have seen this lead to a 60 second roundtrip time.
- Possibly some of the hosts are dealing with being behind a NAT. If you are behind a NAT, Skype may route your calls through other Skype users. If you are not behind a NAT, then Skype may route other users' calls through your hosts. Both situations will lead to a poor user experience.
- You might have multiple layers of NAT. If you haven't checked you can't be sure if there is both NAT in your CPE as well as a CGN deployed by the ISP.

Once you know what your problem is, you can look for solutions to each of the possible problems.

If the link to your site is saturated in one or both directions, you may need to manage the bandwidth. Managing incoming bandwidth is not trivial, because by the time it reaches your equipment, it has already consumed bandwidth on the incoming link. If you are facing this particular issue, a solution could be to not let your users have any direct access to use the ISP link. Instead you route all traffic through a tunnel to a well-connected location (100Mbit/s or more in a data center with at most 1ms latency to the backbone). Once you are routing all traffic through a tunnel, you can manage bandwidth as it enters the tunnel.

If you have a NAT at each site and hosts being behind a NAT is part of your problem, you might gain some advantage from a tunnel between the sites, that way the hosts at each site can communicate with each other without involving a NAT. (I don't know if Skype and Hangouts can benefit from this.)

A tunnel between the two sites will be possible even if one of the sites is behind a CGN. But if both sites are behind CGN, then a tunnel between them is not going to be reliable. If you happen to be in that situation and still find a need for a tunnel between the sites, you have two options. Either you get a public IPv4 address on at least one of the sites, or you get IPv6 at both sites.

Combining a tunnel to a well connected location with a tunnel between the sites may make bandwidth management harder, since you have two sources sending packets down the same pipe, and neither have real time knowledge of how much the other source is sending. This can be addressed by forgetting about the tunnel between the sites and instead route all traffic from one site through the chosen well connected point, regardless of whether you are communicating with the other site or an external location.

Routing all traffic through a data center also avoids most of the addressing problems which could be caused by your ISP, since you would be using addresses from the data center rather than the ISP. You can pick a data center where you can get a host with dual stack connectivity and no NAT.

Due to not being as tied to physical location as the last mile connectivity is, there is more competition among data centers, and this makes it easier find a suitable one. You do still have to pay a bit attention to possibly increased latency. And I certainly wouldn't recommend routing traffic from two different continents through the same data center, so you'll have to find one close to each site.

Answer (score 2):

We faced similar issues and increasing bandwidth did little to address the issues.  The main issues we had were with SharePoint and a CRM.  However, file transfers were painful as well.

We tested and then installed [Riverbed Steelhead WAN optimizers](http://www.riverbed.com/products/wan-optimization/) at offices and the difference was amazing.  Support calls for CRM and SharePoint dropped to almost zero and users were much happier.  It will not necessarily improve Skype and other real-time applications but it can free bandwidth so real-time apps see an improvement.

The big challenge with our apps involved the number of back and forth transactions each page request required.  No matter how large the pipe at each end, the transactions took time.  Basically we monitored the HTTP traffic for the apps and found a simple page in the CRM or SharePoint would take many, many back and forth trips.

Installation was very easy and we were running in less than an hour.  Ongoing tuning allows you to optimize traffic further.

I have no connection with Riverbed and am simply a very satisfied user.

Answer (score 1):

install openwrt or a derivative as your gateways, turn on the sqm-scripts or qos-scripts with fq_codel with your inbound and outbound real rates properly measured and set slightly below that.

Example of results: http://burntchrome.blogspot.com/2014_05_01_archive.html